# Excel VBA - Fit columns to page

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing a report macro to pull data from a database and output the data in Excel. Sometimes the data would span only a couple columns, other times it would have as many as 12 columns. Is there a way for VBA to AutoFit the columns so that it uses up the entire page width?

So if the report had 5 columns, each would be say 1.5" wide and if there were 10 columns, each would be .75" wide.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you talking about a printed page?

Comment: Yes a Printed Page. The data set has only a few rows but a variable number of columns. I want it to all fit on a single printed page with column data across the entirety of the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need **(1)** to divide the window width `ActiveWindow.Width` by the number of columns you want to fit. And then **(2)** apply that resulting width to all the columns you want to fit.

```
w = ActiveWindow.Width / n
Columns(1).Resize(, n).ColumnWidth = w
```

But, **beware**, this will **not** work, because the window width is in *points* and the column width is in *chars*, so you will have to calculate a conversion function.

```
Function pointsToChars(x) As Integer
  p = Range("A1").Width
  c = Range("A1").ColumnWidth
  pointsToChars = x * c / p
End Function
```

and invoke it finally in your code

```
Sub ResizeColumnWidths(n)
  w = ActiveWindow.Width / n
  Columns(1).Resize(, n).ColumnWidth = pointsToChars(w)
End Sub
```